# Excel Chart drops to Zero

Tags: excel, graph

I have a chart which shows performance for the whole year. After the data runs out, it assumes zero, and drops down as pictured. I would like it to just stop at May.

**I have already done =NA(), ="", 0, and [BLANK]**(as per various internet suggestions for this issue) and none of these solutions have worked. I have 6 other charts on the sheet which work perfectly, two of which required the =NA() to work correctly, so it's just something about this sheet/data.

[image][image]

Comment: uhm so what do you want to happen?

Comment: You could maybe make the data source range of the chart just go through May and manually make sure that the axis still goes to the desired month. Another idea -- if the other charts work perfectly, you could just delete this chart, copy one that works, and then edit the data source range. You might have inadvertently changes some setting on this chart

Comment: Thanks for the tip John Coleman! Deleting it and copying a working one solved it.